# How do I enable the internal 32MHz clock on an XMEGA avr in assembly?

Tags: avr-gcc, xmega

This is the C code that I currently use to enable the 32MHz clock:

```
CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
OSC.CTRL = OSC_RC32MEN_bm;
while(!(OSC.STATUS & OSC_RC32MRDY_bm));
CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
CLK.CTRL = CLK_SCLKSEL_RC32M_gc;
```

But this code needs to be compiled with some form of optimization enabled (`-Os` is suggested). Is there a way to do this in assembly without optimizations enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if you are using Atmel Studio, the easiest way to do this is to compile your project using `-Os` and then view the contents of the `*.lss` file inside the `debug` directory. This file contains the C code in conjunction with the compiled assembly code:

```
CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
3226:   88 ed           ldi r24, 0xD8   ; 216
3228:   84 bf           out 0x34, r24   ; 52
OSC.CTRL = OSC_RC32MEN_bm;
322a:   82 e0           ldi r24, 0x02   ; 2
322c:   80 93 50 00     sts 0x0050, r24
while(!(OSC.STATUS & OSC_RC32MRDY_bm));
3230:   80 91 51 00     lds r24, 0x0051
3234:   81 ff           sbrs    r24, 1
3236:   fc cf           rjmp    .-8         ; 0x3230 <main+0x2c>
CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
3238:   88 ed           ldi r24, 0xD8   ; 216
323a:   84 bf           out 0x34, r24   ; 52
CLK.CTRL = CLK_SCLKSEL_RC32M_gc;
323c:   91 e0           ldi r25, 0x01   ; 1
323e:   90 93 40 00     sts 0x0040, r25
```

Using the information from this file, you can modify your C code to this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("ldi r24, 0xD8");
__asm__ __volatile__("out 0x34, r24");      // CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
__asm__ __volatile__("ldi r24, 0x02");
__asm__ __volatile__("sts 0x0050, r24");    // OSC.CTRL = OSC_RC32MEN_bm;
__asm__ __volatile__("lds r24, 0x0051");
__asm__ __volatile__("sbrs r24, 1");        
__asm__ __volatile__("rjmp .-8");           // while(!(OSC.STATUS & OSC_RC32MRDY_bm));
__asm__ __volatile__("ldi r24, 0xD8");
__asm__ __volatile__("out 0x34, r24");      // CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
__asm__ __volatile__("ldi   r25, 0x01");
__asm__ __volatile__("sts   0x0040, r25");  // CLK.CTRL = CLK_SCLKSEL_RC32M_gc;
```

This inline assembly was tested working against an `ATXMEGA32A4U` with no optimizations enabled. Alternatively, you could add an assembly file to your project and create a function in assembler, but this requires no knowledge of assembly to implement.

If you are interested in the avr instruction set, more information can be found [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The optimisations are because the CTRL register must be updated within 4 clocks of the protection register. 
In AVR Studio there are macros which will achieve the same thing, without needing the optimisations, for example:

```
_PROTECTED_WRITE(CLK.CTRL, CLK_SCLKSEL_RC32M_gc);
```